# Аргументы в C в запущенном состоянии

Tags: c

Вопрос для знатоков C. Google меня не понял из за специфики вопроса. Есть программа написанная на C. При запуске принимает аргументы (argv). Суть вопроса, можно ли передавать аргументы, после запуска программы. То есть.
1. Запускаю программу с начальными аргументами:

```
$ prog.c arg1 arg2
```

2. после запуска, программа выполняет какие то алгоритмы и мне понадобилось внести новые аргументы

```
$ prog.c arg3 arg4
```

!Важное примечание, программа не должна запускаться заново.

Comment: Аргументы командной строки добавить невозможно. Используйте любой другой способ связи с приложением, например стандартный ввод или сокеты

Comment: Пояснить остолбенение не позволяет?

Comment: @andreymal спасибо. Понял

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Откуда возникла идея переопределять `argv`, особенно если программу перезапускать нельзя? Если "программа не должна запускаться заново", то что тогда должно запускаться заново? Если перезапускается какая-то внутренняя функция, то что мешает ее оторвать от `argv` вообще и передавать туда вручную что угодно?

Comment: Спасибо за внимание к данной теме. Можно считать, что она  закрыта. Socket - решение

Answer (score 1):

1. Запускаете программу и создаёте какой-нибудь канал общения с ней (сокет, пайп и т.д., см. [межпроцессное взаимодействие](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5))
2. При следующем запуске ищете уже запущеный экземпляр и, если находите, передаёте ему через этот канал новые аргументы. Если не находите - счиаете что это первый запуск, тогда см. пункт 1.

Comment: Спасибо. Сокет помочь должен

Comment: @БогданЛещенко С сокетами будьте осторожнее. В системе нельзя открыть более одного слушающего сокета на одном порту

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, unix-сокеты никто не отменял пока.

Comment: @AntonShchyrov возьму на заметку.